# The existence of several Application instances does not cause a problem?

Tags: android, kotlin, containers, viewmodel

I defined a container class and a class that inherits from the Application, according to the instructions of Google tutorials.

```
class MyAppApplication: Application() {

    lateinit var container: AppContainer
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        container = AppContainer(this)
    }

}
```

1.I need this container in several places of my application. And for this, I need to create an instance of the Application class every time. Doesn't this cause multiple instances of Application class? And if the answer is yes, won't there be a problem?

```
class AppContainer(private val context: Context) {
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    // ...
}
```

2.This way, the retrofit Instance and the rest of the properties I declared inside the container will not be created more than once? (for each Instance of container) (And as far as I know, it should not be made of two retrofits.)

If my questions are basic, I would be grateful if you could introduce a source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense at all to create an instance of an Application. The OS creates your one and only valid Application instance on your behalf. Any instance that you create will be invalid and won't work. It will throw lots of NullPointerExceptions and other errors if you try to do anything with it.

Maybe you are confused about how the property you have created is local to the Application instance. Even if you instantiate more Application classes (which will be invalid), each of them will be referencing different AppContainer instances.

To be able to access your one-and-only valid AppContainer instance, you should put it in a companion object (or you could put it in a top-level property outside of any class or object).

```
class MyAppApplication: Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var container: AppContainer
            private set
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        container = AppContainer(this)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact, apparently this is what is written in the Android tutorial: Please take a look at these:  [InventoryApplication.kt](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/inventory/InventoryApplication.kt)    and  [AppViewModelProvider.kt](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/inventory/ui/AppViewModelProvider.kt). The class inherited from Application() is instantiated once for each view model.

Comment: That's another way to do it, and it is not instantiating new Application instances. See the last two lines where if you call it repeatedly it retrieves the same instance over and over: https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/inventory/ui/AppViewModelProvider.kt#L67 I wasn't familiar with CreationExtras. It seems to be a recent addition to the ViewModel library. It's like a Map. That code is retrieving the sole application instance from the Map.

Comment: oh yes These two lines change everything : fun CreationExtras.inventoryApplication(): InventoryApplication =
    (this[AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY] as InventoryApplication)